# Dielectric properties of polarizing beam splitter

Tags: optics, material-science, polarization, dielectric, optical-materials

Are all polarizing beam splitters made up of dielectric materials?If so, what kind of dielectric materials are actually used to make them?

Answer (score 0):

No not all are made up of dielectric materials.

Comment: Some more exposition seems to be in order for this answer.

Comment: Answering the first sentence surley leaves the 2nd moote?